# How would I get my background image to repeat forever in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have these two images that are the same image and I want them to repeat so it looks like the background is moving. I have this code but only one of the background images goes through then it goes back to the grey screen. The other background image doesn't follow the first one. How do I fix that? Thanks! (This is in swift xcode)

```
 func spawnBackground() {

    let cloud = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CloudBg")
    let cloud2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CloudBg2")


    cloud.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width + cloud.frame.size.width / 2,cloud.frame.height / 2)
    cloud.setScale(1.35)
    cloud.zPosition = -15

    cloud2.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
    cloud2.setScale(1.35)
    cloud.zPosition = -15


    let moveTop = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: cloud.size.height, duration:   NSTimeInterval(CGFloat(gameSpeed) * cloud.size.height))
    cloud.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveTop))
    cloud2.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveTop))



    addChild(cloud)
    addChild(cloud2)


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for an action sequence like this:

```
  let cloud = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CloudBg")
        let cloud2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CloudBg2")


        cloud.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width + cloud.frame.size.width / 2,cloud.frame.height / 2)
        cloud.setScale(1.35)
        cloud.zPosition = -15

        cloud2.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
        cloud2.setScale(1.35)
        cloud.zPosition = -15

        var actionone = SKAction.moveToX(0, y: cloud.size.height, duration:   NSTimeInterval(CGFloat(gameSpeed) * cloud.size.height))

        var actiontwo = SKAction.runBlock({
            cloud.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width + cloud.frame.size.width / 2,cloud.frame.height / 2)
        })

        cloud.runAction(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([actionone,actiontwo])))
```

Of course you will have to edit this code to work where when one cloud reaches a certain point the other one begins, but that is the general idea.

Comment: thanks for the help but its still doing the same thing before where the first background image would work but then nothing else would follow or repeat.

Comment: Well I didn't do the second background image in that code. Only the first. Also, it should be move moveToX I think. moveByX with a value of 0 isn't going to do anything...